# sharing live data

Tags: android, performance, live

I'm currently developing an application which should share the location of multiple clients live. It is important that the locations are always up to date. I would like to ask what's the best way of doing so with keeping performance in mind. I currently only have a web services in mind which handles the locations and the client fetches the data every X seconds from the server or live updates with firebase.

Answer (score 1):

I'm strongly recommend to use synchronized DB, such as coutchDB/PouchDB or similar, in that why the DB framework will be responsible to sync all clients without the need to handle each client separately.

Comment: So every client updates it's position every X seconds to the DB and the will sync it to all clients?
I'm just wondering if the performance would be better if when the sync is always in an Intervall.